# Angular Calendar - On click get the date

Tags: angularjs, calendar, angular-ui

In angular calendar there is an method AlertOnEventClick, which shows an alert when clicked on event. I am trying to alert the user with the date on which the user is clicked.

[image]

In this calendar if the user clicks 4 in calendar, i want to alert the user "you clicked 4". I am not sure how to do this..Is there any method to alert the date on which user clicked in Angular Calendar..

Comment: can you please add some code or provide a fiddle/ plunker?

Comment: @varit05 I have integrated this angular calendar into an application, and customized alot of code. The angular calendar code i took it from here - http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/

Answer (score 0):

Angular UI calendar is angular wrapper of [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/). You can view doc of [eventClick](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/) to know more. Each such event gives you an [event object](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/). Here start and end will provide you time at which user has clicked.